# React Native mobile App - best approach to internationalise images

Tags: react-native, internationalization

what (libraries, principles, techniquess, tips&tricks ) do you use for **image** internationalisation in your mobile apps with React Native?

For example image where is poster in different language.

[image]
[image]

I'm coming from Android world and there it is done like this (just add the locale to drawable folder and best fitting image for phone setup is then taken):

```
src/main/res/
            drawable/ = any universal
            drawable-hdpi/ = any universal for hdpi
            drawable-sk-hdpi/ = override specific when locale is set to sk (Slovak)
```

Is there any similar solution, or do I have to write it by myslef (I can imagine simple library)?

*DISCLAIMER: the boy on picture is not smoking,  he holds flutter - a device used by people with respiratory conditions to help loosen secretions (phlegm) in the chest.*